# Using Ditto across a windows network

Tags: network, windows, copy-paste

I am trying to use the ditto command after connecting to a PC across a network with a shared C drive. I try:

```
ditto -V smb://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/C/users/john.smithy/documents /volumes/"macintosh hd"/users/john.smithy/documents
```

but I get an error that the path can't be found!! Even though I am connected and can navigate via Finder.

Please help this hapless Windows kiddie make this command work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use proper capitalization because paths in arguments are case-sensitive and I'm not sure if the double quotes are set properly to escape the blank. So try instead:

```
ditto -V smb://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/C/Users/john.smithy/Documents /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/john.smithy/Documents
```

or

```
ditto -V smb://10.XXX.XXX.XXX/C/Users/john.smithy/Documents "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/john.smithy/Documents"
```

This doesn't apply if one or both of the *"Documents"* folder really have the name "documents". At least the standard OS X volumes and users folder have the names *Volumes* and *Users*!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - as I have already connected the drive then it is a mounted drive so the correct way is:

ditto -v /Volumes/C/Users/john.smithy/Documents ~/Documents